# Take photo and get image view android

Tags: android

I have prblem with getting image view:
Shooting a camera and want to image to display in layout.
Initially contains the absolute path of the file in the database and is displayed as text, but now I want to show a picture. How to do this?

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // get view reference
                View view = convertView;
                // if null 
                if(view == null) {
                        // inflate new layout
                        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.acivity_layout_list_item, null);
                        // create a holder
                        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
                        // find controls
                        holder.txtImage = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtImage);
                        ... other holder.txtparameters
                        // set data structure to view
                        view.setTag(holder);
                }
                 // get selected user info
                UserInfo userInfo = mListUserInfo.get(position);
                // if not null
                if(userInfo != null) {
                        // query data structure
                        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
                        // set data to display
                        holder.txtImage.setText(userInfo.getmImage());
                        ...
                }               

                // return view
                return view;
        }
 static class ViewHolder {
            private TextView txtImage;
            ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear to me.

But as per my understanding you have stored image file's path into database. and want to display image from that path.

Then Do following steps

1. Take ImageView instead TextView.
2. Convert Image from File Path

   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
   imageView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
3. Now display this Bitmap in ImageView

Later you can use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for implementing lazy loading.

Comment: Yes, it is my question.

Comment: Answer is there for you buddy. Let me know if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to set Capture image from Camera in ImageView than, this is Complite example,

### In click

```
camera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 100);
        }
    });
```

### OnActivity

```
if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            s_bmp = bp;
            ph.setImageBitmap(bp);

        }
```